# ORA-01861: literal does not match format string use oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data field in oracle database, i need to update my data field and use add_months function to add 3 more month as show below, my table name psm_voucher.

```
Name                            Null?    Type
------------------------------- -------- ----
BARCODE                                  VARCHAR2(20)
EXPDT                                    VARCHAR2(8)

Select barcode,expdt from psm_voucher where barcode='BBCV101670';

BARCODE              EXPDT
-------------------- --------
BBCV101670           20201231
```

then I try update query as below but fail

```
Update psm_voucher set expdt=add_months(expdt,3) where barcode='BBCV101670';
update psm_voucher set expdt=add_months(expdt,3) where barcode='BBCV101670'
                                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

Your kinds help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As date in your table is stored as a string, you will need to follows some basic steps:

- convert string to date
- add 3 months into converted date
- convert the date back to string which can be stored in your table.

Use the following query:

```
update psm_voucher 
   set expdt= to_char(add_months(to_date(expdt,'YYYYMMDD'),3), 'YYYYMMDD')
 where barcode='BBCV101670'
```

Comment: i tried above query but show error ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: yes, you right, it work! Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of your problem is that you are storing a date as a string.  Fix the data model, so `EXPDT` is a `date`.

Then your code will work.

Comment: ok, I try convert my string to date but fail, 
update psm_voucher set expdt=to_date(add_months(expdt,3),'YYYYMMDD') where barcode='BBCV101670'
                                                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Comment: @Hoongwaikong - Think about what your attempt does. It adds 3 months to EXPDT **as is** (while it is a string), and only after this operation is performed, it is converted to date. Does that make any sense to you? If adding three months to a string failed in your original attempt, why would that change, only because you add a processing step **after** that? Do you understand why your second attempt failed exactly in the same way as the first, and what the *correct* solution is?

Answer (score 0):

You should *never rely on a default string to date conversion* which you are doint when you pass a VARCHAR string to the function `add_months`

```
with dt as (
select '20201231' EXPDT from dual)
select
 add_months(expdt,3)
from dt;
```

This fauls with `ORA-01861: literal does not match format string` because you session DATE format is other that you stored string `20201231`

You must explicitely convert `to_date` using the right format masks, based on your example it is `YYYYMMDD`

```
with dt as (
select '20201231' EXPDT from dual)
select
 add_months(to_date(expdt,'YYYYMMDD'),3)  as EXPDT_D
from dt;

EXPDT_D            
-------------------
31.03.2021 00:00:00
```

And yes, you'll have less problems while storing DATEs in a `DATE` format column